# "Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server" with pg_connect on localhost

Tags: php, postgresql, database-connection

I've a server with postgresql installed on the postgres user. When I do:

```
su - postgres
[entering the password]
psql
```

I can then execute queries on the database, that works fine.

However, from my php script (running on my own account):

```
$dbconnection = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=XXXXXXX ");
```

(password crossed out of course)

I then get the message:

> PHP Warning:  pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server:
> FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres" FATAL:
> password authentication failed for user "postgres" in
> /home/username/script.php on line 18

I tried a lot of variations on the login string, but I keep getting the same message. Any ideas how I could try to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the current configuration for pg_hba.conf? And did you set a password for the database rol "postgres" ? su - postgres is for the Linux user "postgres", not for the database role "postgres". If you can start psql without entering the password, it looks like pg_hba.conf uses "trust" and not "password" of even better "md5". Or did you create a .pgpass file?

Comment: Yes! I indeed confused the linux user "postgres" and the database role "postgres". I did know that they where different, and created them both at installation, but ended up mixing the passwords up. It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your postgres may not listen on a network interface but on a filesystem socket in stead. What if you leave out host=/port= entirely?

Also, if you know the socketpath (and it's non-default), you may use that as host= argument

Comment: leaving out host and port unfortunately doesn't solve it. Only instead of 

  FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

I get:

  FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

I don't know about the socketpath, but it is a default installation of ubuntu server, and I used most of the default settings during install.

Answer (score -1):

Be careful, the following (too short) connection string causes the mentioned error message ("Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "halmai" in..."):

`pg_connect("dbname=halmai user=halmai password=halmai");`

However, the more complete connection string works well:

`pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=halmai user=halmai password=halmai");`

My environment: php7.0.8.